# White background in autofill search box

Tags: javascript

I know very little of Javascript, but I managed to create a search box with an autofill in it,
But now my question is can I format the background of the names, so it is not transparent anymore (ref screenshot):

[image]

This is the code I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        $(".auto").autocomplete({
            source: "search.php",
            minLength: 1
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: We'll need more code than that.

Comment: What other code do you need? The one of of search.php?

Comment: Include jquery.ui.css and jquery.ui.js based on you jquery version. It will set style automatically.

Comment: I don't know where to find these files? Should I create them and put a property in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to insufficient information, I am supposing that you have used *unordered (bulleted) list* to create the list.
Now as I see, you can set *background-color* property to white (#fff) to make it non-transparent.

It can be done like this:

```
ul{background-color:white;} //but it will set background color for all *unordered (bulleted) list*  to white.
```

While you can use assign some class name to the *unordered (bulleted) list* elements dynamically and the set then property like this:

```
.className{background-color:white;}
```

I am not much into web development, just some old experiences with friends and some research made me to this answer. Let me know if it works.

> Sources:
>
> [CSS background-color Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp)  w3schools.com
>
> [HTML  Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp)  w3schools.com